# How to install BURG on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, burg

I cannot find any PPA that contains BURG for Ubuntu 16.04. How can I install it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the PPA I used since 14.04 has Xenial packages!

Add the repository with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg`.

Then `sudo apt-get update`

You can then install the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
sudo burg-install "(sd0)"
sudo update-burg
```

Change "(sd0)" with your corresponding hard disk: "(sd1)", "(sd2)" etc.

*I haven't tried it myself since I have yet to upgrade to Xenial, but I hope that helps.*

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the terminal
2. type `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg` press Enter. Type your password. [you need to be root user]
3. Next type `sudo apt-get update` and let the process complete.
4. Next type `sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes`. This will install the burg bootloader.
5. You will be prompted with options while installation. press Tab to switch to OK button and hit Enter
6. In the next screen select the path for the bootloader to install with space and hit tab and Enter.

Its an easy process.
7.Afterwards to boot to burg type `sudo burg-emu`
Use

F1 Help
F2 Change Theme
F3 Change Resolution
Arrow-keys to move

8. After configuring reboot and Voila!!

hope this helps