# Replace Grub with Windows loader

Tags: bootloader

I hav a Dell inspiron 3000 working on windows 10. I recently installed ubuntu 16.04. The problem is that now when I boot Grub boot loader gives the options and I'm not very fond of it. I would like the windows boot loader (the GUI). Pls help me with the steps to do so

Comment: Err… I remember long ago I had multiple Windows on one PC with no GNU/Linux *(I didn't know other systems back then)*, it indeed has options to choose between them. But its interface is worse than that of Grub — Grub has even the possibility to set a wallpaper! So, I didn't get actually, why would you want that loader.

Comment: Don't mess with this kind of stuff unless you're a techie. Otherwise, you can and **will** break things.

Comment: Okay, since the question has answer, I'd add also: Windows Bootloader is pretty lame in comparison to Grub. The worst problem from a point of a common user is that its loader supports almost nothing of existing OSes, whilst Grub does support a bunch of them. But ofc that's not the only thing why their bootloader so bad, for full comparison you could look [at this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_boot_loaders).

Answer (score 2):

If you are not fond of grub than you can try BURG. It has better GUI than the windows boot loader (Trust me on this one). You can select different themes for that as well. Also if you have dual booted your system then you can remove other options from the options screen and set just two options i.e WINDOWS and LINUX. To know how to install BURG here is the link :
[How to install BURG on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775467/how-to-install-burg-on-ubuntu-16-04)