# Is BURG still supported?

Tags: grub2, burg

I would like to make my boot screen a bit nicer, so in a search i stumbled across BURG. When I try to add the ppa and update [like the instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775467/how-to-install-burg-on-ubuntu-16-04), it returns a 404 error at `sudo apt update`. Has burg just been killed, because I cannot find any place where i could download a separate installer.

Running Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: No, not with that PPA no. It goes up to 16.04 only. It's unlikely the owner will ever update it again. You may try editing the source and change it to `xenial` but be warned it may not work and may have unintended effects. BURG is old and shouldn't be used anyway. I'm not sure if it even works in UEFI mode.

Comment: All systems since Windows 8 came out 5 years ago are now UEFI. And then if you want graphic boot manager you can use rEFInd. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ But does not work on older BIOS systems.